# How to read values form arraylist,which in interface?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

My interface is

```
public interface IDisplayListQueue
{
    void BindQueueData();
    System.Collections.ArrayList QueueDataSource { get; set; }
}
```

In the page load  adding values to list

```
IDisplayListQueue dataEntryQueue;
dataEntryQueue.QueueDataSource.Add(new { QueueID = queue.QueueID, LinkText = queueName, Uid = sentinel });
```

After the page loads I want to find the values ,for example QueueID  in dataEntryQueue.

So ,I am trying to write the code like this

```
dataEntryQueue.QueueDataSource.Contains("122");
```

I am not able to to find the above ID,even though it is exits.QueueDataSource values are in objects and after QueueDataSource Ia m not able to get the QueueID  property.

Comment: Any reason you still want to use the non-generic `ArrayList` if you're really using C# 4?

Comment: how can i use without non-generic ArrayList?

Comment: Well it's hard to know without having more information about what you're trying to achieve. It's quite possibly that `IDisplayListQueue` should be generic to start with...

Comment: This is C# not vb.net - perhaps you need to remove the vb.net tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your own class wich contains fields `QueueID, LinkText, Uid`, and use `List<OwnClass>` insted of array list

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create instances of an interface directly. You'll have to create an object, which implements IDisplayListQueue and then access this object.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new anonymous type with a `QueueID` property, and you want the `Contains` method to look up an object based on that ID, right? But `Contains` has no way of knowing that "122" should be matched to `QueueID`. The only way it can compare different objects inside the list is by their references, their memory locations, and that's not what you're after.

So what can you do? Instead of using Contains, you would want to use the LINQ method `Any`, giving it a way to explicitly check the QueueID property:

```
if (dataEntryQueue.QueueDataSource
                  .Any(queueThingie => queueThingie.QueueID = "122"))
{
    // found it!
}
```

However, this won't work. Why? Because `ArrayList` stores `object`s, and it doesn't know your `queueThingie` has a `QueueID` property.

So what can you do? Avoid mixing shiny new anonymous types with old and clunky ArrayLists. Create a simple `QueueThingie` class withh the three properties you want, and then you can use LINQ's `Any` to find the one you want. In fact, if your `QueueThingie` implements the `IEqualityComparer` interface, it will even be possible to use `ArrayList.Contains`.